# Local file vs. ftp file

Tags: python, ftp, gdal

I can successfully get the information about the format of a raster file using GDAL library when the file is located on my local file system:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
filename= "MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf"
dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
print ( dataset.GetDriver().ShortName,dataset.GetDriver().LongName)
```

Output:

```
('HDF4', 'Hierarchical Data Format Release 4')
```

But, when I try this with the same raster file, but this time located on an ftp server, I get an error:

```
import gdal   
from gdalconst import *
filename="ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/5/MOD11A1/2012/193/MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf"
dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
print ( dataset.GetDriver().ShortName,dataset.GetDriver().LongName)
```

Output with error:

```
ERROR 4: `/vsimem/http_1/MOD11A1.A2012193.h11v11.005.2012196013534.hdf' not recognised as a supported file format.

('HDF4', 'Hierarchical Data Format Release 4')
```

Why is this?

Comment: You can't just give FTP URLs and expect them to be fetched most of the time. You'll need to write code to explicitly download the file, then open it.

Comment: @Linuxios I know how to download the file. I just wanted to do it more straightforward, without having to download files.
In both cases, the output is printed out corectly, but in the second case (ftp case), the output is printed along with the error.

Comment: Then the server you're fetching from is probably reporting an incorrect file type. That's my guess.

Comment: @Linuxios But the local file of the first case is downloaded from the same ftp link that gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `/vsicurl/` prefix. My GDAL build doesnt support the HDF4 driver, so i cant test your url. But normally it should work:

```
gdalinfo /vsicurl/http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=Europe_2_02.2013259.terra.2km.tif
```

See this link for some more information:
http://erouault.blogspot.nl/2012/05/new-gdal-virtual-file-system-to-read.html